# Wordpress post query and loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type with a couple of custom post fields.
What I am trying to do is to display field 1 of all posts, then put some html content, and then display field 2 for all posts. So, the structure will be something like this:

> - Field 1 for post 1
> - Field 1 for post 2
> - Field 1 for post 3
> - Field 1 for post 4
>
> HTML CONTETENT GOES HERE
>
> - Field 2 for post 1
> - Field 2 for post 2
> - Field 2 for post 3
> - Field 2 for post 4

Is there a better way to do it than to query the posts twice? It's the exact same set of posts.

Currently my Post query and loop looks like this

```
    // Query to display Field 1 for all posts
        <?php
            $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'pbt',
                'posts_per_page' => 5
            ) );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) :  while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>
        FIELD 1 DATA GOES HERE
        <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

MY HTML CONTENT GOES HERE

    // Query to display Field 2 of posts
        <?php
            $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'pbt',
                'posts_per_page' => 5
            ) );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) :  while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>
        FIELD 2 DATA GOES HERE
        <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it?
As you can see, I'm repeating the query and post loop twice in order to put html data between them.

Is there a way I could pull field 1 for all posts, then pause the loop or something, put html content, and then pull field 2 for all posts without repeating the query?

Answer (score 1):

@shtarley

May be it is a better way to make two arrays from one loop i.e.

$field1[];
$field2[];

Store all the values from wp_query loop inside this two arrays and after that just show first array and then your html and after that second array.I don't know but i am assuming that you need both fields on different different palces.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Query to display Field 1 for all posts
    <?php
        $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'pbt',
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        ) );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) :  while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>
    FIELD 1 DATA GOES HERE
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

MY HTML CONTENT GOES HERE

// Query to display Field 2 of posts

    <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>
    FIELD 2 DATA GOES HERE
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```